# Could Google read Map Api InfoWindow html content?

Tags: javascript, google

I used google map api.
I read some high protected data on the my HTML page. And write them into InfoWindow on google maps using javascript.

Could google read infowindow html content?

There are no answer for me, or i cant understand :(

> - Map size and location for retrieving map tiles and copyrights
> - Addresses for geocoding
> - Direction and Elevation requests
> - Locations around which to search for Places
> - KML when using KmlLayer

Answer (score 1):

If you include any third party script in your page, the authors *could* potentially read any data on the page. That applies to Google Maps, any third party library hosts, advertising providers...

If the data is sufficiently high risk to be worried about Google stealing it, don't use any third party scripts.

Comment: Thanx Matthew, this just not fair, i have no chance to use another map. if google can read my data, i have to cancel this mini project.

Answer (score 0):

### Use an iframe

The short answer is yes, if you load a third party script into your webpage, it is possible for Google to inject tracking scripts that could reveal your protected information.

However, iframes can be used to sandbox the contents of one webpage inside of another webpage, such that it can't touch what is going on outside of that sandbox.  So, what you can do it create a page that you can send parameters to for the map, and that page loads the Google map with only what you send to it.

So, your secure webpage might contain an iframe that looks like:

```
<iframe src="https://secureapplication.com/googlemap.php?width=<?=$width?>&height=<?=$height?>&address=<?=$adress?>&direction=<?=$direction?>(etc...)" width="<?=$width?>" height="<?=$height?>"></iframe>
```

This way, googlemap.php is its own page that that is treated as coming from a different origin than the secure page.  You give it all of the behaviors and parameters it needs to load the map, but none of the secure info.  That way, all that Google can possibly see is that its API was used to generate a page containing nothing but a map.  As long as none of the parameters the API needs to generate the map are Private Information unto itself, this should satisfy your security concerns.